# Getting an unhandled exception with a defined catch block

Tags: vb.net, exception, unhandled-exception, unhandled

So I'm working in VB.Net and I am occasionally getting an unhandled exception.  What I don't get is that I have a catch block for said exception.

Here's a sample of what I'm talking about.

```
        Try
            If MyTask3 IsNot Nothing Then
                MyTask3.Control(TaskAction.Abort)
                MyTask3.Dispose()
            End If
        Catch ex As DaqException
            ErrorMessage = ex.ToString()
            MyTask3.Dispose()
        Catch ex As AccessViolationException
            ErrorMessage = ex.ToString()
            MyTask3.Dispose()
        Catch ex As ObjectDisposedException
            ErrorMessage = ex.ToString()
        Catch ex As Exception
            ErrorMessage = ex.ToString()
        Finally
            Task3Aborted = True
        End Try
```

So in testing the above code snippet, I sometimes get an AccessViolationException (which the debugger says is unhandled even though there is a Catch for it).  I step through the code and the catch that execute is the ObjectDisposedException.

So is this a case where I'm getting two exceptions thrown and only one is handled while the other is unhandled?  Is that even possible?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Does one exception occur inside a handler of another?

Comment: That is an excellent point.  I didn't even think of that.  I will have to put a break in each of the exceptions to see if that is what is happening.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Starting with the .NET Framework 4, AccessViolationException exceptions thrown by the common language runtime are not handled by the catch statement in a structured exception handler if the exception occurs outside of the memory reserved by the common language runtime. To handle such an AccessViolationException exception, you should apply the HandleProcessCorruptedStateExceptionsAttribute attribute to the method in which the exception is thrown.

I think this is your problem. You can read more [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.accessviolationexception(v=vs.110).aspx).
Mark the function with the `HandleProcessCorruptedStateExceptions` attribute to handle this exception. You may need to add `legacyCorruptedState­­ExceptionsPolicy=true` to your *app.config*.
You can read [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419661.aspx#id0070035) if you want to understand whats happening.

Comment: I think that did it.  Thanks so much for your help Kimmax!!!  I'd vote it up if I could.  :(

Comment: Sorry @Kimmax.  It's my first question, so I'm a newbie.

Comment: @fmarcelino I know, no problem :)